# Adicionar DLL externa em um projeto que utiliza Docker

Tags: c#, docker, assembly

Estou tentando rodar um projeto em docker, porém sempre ocorre o erro de assembly quando tento utilizar o comando Docker build. Compilando o projeto pelo selfproject e rodando pelo Docker direto pelo visual studio funciona normalmente, apenas pelo docker build ocorre o erro.

Criei um projeto de teste para tentar simular o erro.

Comando executado: docker build -t dllextensions .

Dockerfile utilizado, que foi criado pelo próprio Visual Studio

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ConsumerExternalDll.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./ConsumerExternalDll.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "ConsumerExternalDll.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ConsumerExternalDll.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsumerExternalDll.dll"]
```

Referência da dll que ocorre o erro:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="DllGeneratorExtensions">
      <HintPath>..\output\Debug\net6.0\DllGeneratorExtensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

`Não é apenas com essa, qualquer dll externa ele não ocorre o mesmo erro.`
O namespace da Dll que estou tentando consumir é DllGeneratorExtensions, que tem apenas um método de teste para tentar simular o erro.

Output ao executar o comando docker build

```
  > [build 7/7] RUN dotnet build "ConsumerExternalDll.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build:
#15 0.579 MSBuild version 17.3.1+2badb37d1 for .NET
#15 1.090   Determining projects to restore...
#15 1.388   All projects are up-to-date for restore.
#15 1.578 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.401/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "DllGeneratorExtensions". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [/src/ConsumerExternalDll.csproj]
#15 2.404 /src/Program.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DllGeneratorExtensions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/src/ConsumerExternalDll.csproj]
#15 2.430
#15 2.430 Build FAILED.
#15 2.430
#15 2.430 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.401/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "DllGeneratorExtensions". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [/src/ConsumerExternalDll.csproj]
#15 2.430 /src/Program.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DllGeneratorExtensions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/src/ConsumerExternalDll.csproj]
#15 2.430     1 Warning(s)
#15 2.430     1 Error(s)
#15 2.431
#15 2.431 Time Elapsed 00:00:01.78
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet build "ConsumerExternalDll.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build]: exit code: 1
```

Existe alguma forma de carregar essas dlls pelo docker file ou é algum outro processo para que consiga executar?

Answer (score -3):

1. em um projeto .NET o contexto de build é criado no diretório acima do diretório do CSPROJ
2. Isso fará com que você tenha de referenciar os paths (semelhante a um dockerfile produzido pelo visual studio)
3. Talvez você consiga contornar isso com uma feature recente chamada multiple contexts. Mas ainda é uma feature muito recente. Faz como o visual studio faz que é sucesso.
   Da forma como você fez, você não pode ter 2 projetos na mesma solution.